# iniciar session antes de entrar a la tienda (usuarios)

Tags: prestashop

Mi problemática es la siguiente, un  usuario (comprador) no deberia de poder hacer nada en la tienda sin antes tener una session iniciada, por lo tanto ¿como es posible que con prestashop haga que la primera vista (obligatoria) sea la de inicio de session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FrontController: (crear un override)

if ($this->auth && !$this->context->customer->isLogged($this->guestAllowed)) {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication'.($this->authRedirection ? '&back='.$this->authRedirection : ''));
        }

por

if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && $this->php_self != 'authentication' && $this->php_self != 'password'){
             Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication?back=my-account');
        }